# Problem generating loading scores of Principle Components in R

Tags: r

I have completed PCA in R using example code from stat quest https://github.com/StatQuest/pca_demo/blob/master/pca_demo.R 
(with my own data in it, dataframe called "PCA4", which was then named PCstats for the PCA) :

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8igU.png)

> dput(PCA4)

```
structure(list(X40.45cm = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X50.55cm = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 64L, 96L, 0L, 0L), X60.65cm = c(0L, 
3L, 1L, 64L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 128L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 352L, 512L, 160L, 
0L), X70.75cm = c(1L, 7L, 0L, 32L, 33L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 256L, 32L, 
0L, 0L, 352L, 544L, 320L, 0L), X80.85cm = c(109L, 1L, 2L, 11L, 
164L, 34L, 2L, 64L, 480L, 32L, 160L, 96L, 352L, 1184L, 224L, 
32L)), .Names = c("X40.45cm", "X50.55cm", "X60.65cm", "X70.75cm", 
"X80.85cm"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

My data consists of samples in the columns and then each row is a type of species and the given number of those found in each sample. 
In order to complete the PCA I had to remove the species names, but I think this may now be hindering my ability to generate loading scores. The code I'm trying to use is below:

```
loading_scores <- PCstats$rotation[,1]
species_scores <- abs(loading_scores)
species_score_ranked <- sort(species_scores, decreasing=TRUE)
top_10_species <- names(species_score_ranked[1:10])

top_10_species 
PCstats$rotation[top_10_species,1]
```

However, when I input this it just says numeric (0) and then NULL.

I apologise if this is badly explained, I've never asked a question on here before, but if you need any more info or clarification please let me know- any help is gratefully received!

Many thanks!

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image.  No one wants to type it all in again  Instead, use `dput` to create a text representation of your data that we can paste into R for testing.

Comment: Hi sorry about that, is what i've put in now correct? Sorry, never used 'dput' before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the original post identifies the columns (measurements) that most contribute to the first principal component. In order to understand the rows that have the largest magnitude on the first component, we must merge the factor scores with the species names, and sort by the absolute value of PC1.

```
data <-structure(list(X40.45cm = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X50.55cm = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
               3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 64L, 96L, 0L, 0L), 
               X60.65cm = c(0L, 
               3L, 1L, 64L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 128L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 352L, 512L, 160L, 
               0L), X70.75cm = c(1L, 7L, 0L, 32L, 33L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 256L, 32L, 
               0L, 0L, 352L, 544L, 320L, 0L), X80.85cm = c(109L, 1L, 2L, 11L, 
               164L, 34L, 2L, 64L, 480L, 32L, 160L, 96L, 352L, 1184L, 224L, 
          32L)), .Names = c("X40.45cm", "X50.55cm", "X60.65cm", "X70.75cm", 
          "X80.85cm"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

# add column for species names
Species <- paste("Species",LETTERS[1:16])
data <- cbind(Species,data)
# pca
princomp <- prcomp(data[,2:ncol(data)],scale. = TRUE)
stats <- summary(princomp)
# return factor scores for first principal component
x_result <- princomp$x[,"PC1"]
```

At this point `x_result` contains the factor scores for principal component 1. Since the scores are in order of the original observations of the data frame input to `princomp()`, we can simply set the simulated species names to the vector with `names(x_result)`, and sort the vector by descending absolute value.

```
names(x_result) <- Species
x_result[order(abs(x_result),decreasing = TRUE)][1:10]
```

and the output:

```
> x_result[order(abs(x_result),decreasing = TRUE)][1:10]
 Species N  Species M  Species B  Species F  Species G  Species C Species I 
-5.8993459 -2.8787001  1.3925053  1.2874129  1.0017446  1.0012497 -0.9691621 
 Species P  Species H  Species J 
 0.9550311  0.9020930  0.8617220  

>
```

### Plotting Factor Scores & Loadings

With the `pcaMethods` package from Bioconductor, we can replicate the analysis and print a pair of plots illustrating the factor scores (observations) and loadings (measurements) on the first two factors.

First, we install Bioconductor and pcaMethods (if necessary),

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
     install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.10")
BiocManager::install("pcaMethods")
library(pcaMethods)
```

Next, we run the analysis with data scaled to unit variance and centered, and generate the plots.

```
speciesPCA <- pca(data[,2:ncol(data)],scale = "uv", center = TRUE)
slplot(speciesPCA, scoresLoadings = c(T,T))
```

[image]

Finally, we extract the factor scores from the `speciesPCA` object, add row names, and print in descending order of the absolute value of `PC1`. Note that `pcaMethods` uses the S4 object model, so we need to use the `@` form of the extract operator to access elements within the object.

```
theScores <- speciesPCA@scores[,1] # get first column PC1 only 
names(theScores) <- Species
theScores[order(abs(theScores),decreasing = TRUE)]
```

...and the output:

```
> theScores[order(abs(theScores),decreasing = TRUE)]
 Species N  Species M  Species B  Species F  Species G  Species C  Species I  Species P  Species H  Species J  Species L 
-5.8993459 -2.8787001  1.3925053  1.2874129  1.0017446  1.0012497 -0.9691621  0.9550311  0.9020930  0.8617220  0.8491550 
 Species O  Species A  Species D  Species E  Species K 
-0.8414228  0.8247330  0.6781688  0.6302041  0.2046116 
>
```

Note that the scores and order match the output from the `prcomp()` version of the analysis.

Comment: Hi @LenGreski , that's exactly what I was looking for thank you! I just ran it through by substituting 'data' with the original dataset of PCA4 and got slightly different results in my output **(Species N Species M Species I Species O Species G Species C Species P Species H Species L Species A 
-3.143797 -2.682618 -1.890504 -1.890177  1.581668  1.581224  1.386696  1.278028  1.213854  1.004267)**- any idea why this might be?

Comment: Which R function did you use to calculate the principal components analysis? If I use `psych::principal()`, I get the following result: **Species N  Species M  Species B  Species F  Species G  Species C  Species I 
 3.0778247  1.5018842 -0.7265021 -0.6716730 -0.5226332 -0.5223750  0.5056342 
 Species P  Species H  Species J 
-0.4982617 -0.4706427 -0.4495802**, which matches the order in my answer, but with different factor scores. Also, what arguments did you use in the function that calculated the PCA?  BTW, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Also, which version of R are you using? I'm using 3.6.3 on OS X.

Comment: Thank you, it has been invaluable so far! I used `prcomp` which was lifted straight from the example code here (I followed everything from line 20 to 44 on there) https://github.com/StatQuest/pca_demo/blob/master/pca_demo.R so it looked like this `PCstats <- prcomp(t(PCA4), scale=TRUE)` .  I'm using R 3.4.3 and Rstudio Version 1.1.423  on macOS.

Comment: Is the original PCA4 data frame 16 rows and 5 columns? the `t(PCA4)` is very important. It means that you've transposed the data. However, if there are only 5 columns before the transpose, the resulting data frame has 5 rows and 16 columns. There aren't enough rows to to do a valid principal components analysis. In the StatQuest example, it starts with more columns than rows so the transposed matrix is valid for a factor analysis.

Comment: Yes it is, ah I see, is there any way around this? I did try it without the `t()` but it plotted all 16 species on the PCA plot, when I only want the 5 samples plotted.

Comment: The Bioconductor `pcaMethods` package has a nice PCA plot that combines factor scores for the observations with loadings for the variables. I'll update my answer to include the code to produce these two charts.

Answer (score 0):

Names will not work for top_10_species, as species_score_ranked is not a data frame. Try this

```
loading_scores <- PCstats$rotation[,1]
species_scores <- abs(loading_scores)
species_score_ranked <- sort(species_scores, decreasing=TRUE)
top_10_species <- match(species_score_ranked[1:10],species_scores)

top_10_species
PCstats$rotation[top_10_species,]
```

Output:

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
> PCstats$rotation[top_10_species,]
            PC1         PC2         PC3         PC4         PC5
 [1,] 0.2938804 -0.06715619  0.06862443  0.12857870  0.11781917
 [2,] 0.2932723 -0.08432870  0.02670414 -0.08688880  0.22867875
 [3,] 0.2869432  0.13535231  0.05421256  0.08940930 -0.36614492
 [4,] 0.2851476  0.12618316 -0.13957539 -0.17127002 -0.04163248
 [5,] 0.2849976 -0.14928654 -0.03024884  0.17614136  0.30544938
 [6,] 0.2843594 -0.15278602 -0.03551544  0.17841931 -0.06085204
 [7,] 0.2843594 -0.15278602 -0.03551544  0.17841931 -0.06085204
 [8,] 0.2843594 -0.15278602 -0.03551544  0.17841931 -0.06085204
 [9,] 0.2841340  0.05627504  0.25523009  0.03263271  0.00697634
[10,] 0.2710251 -0.20911054 -0.01754100 -0.56694280  0.01517564
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!